# What is larger: zipped json or zipped xml?

Tags: xml, json, zip

if I compare 2 data files containing the same data, but one of them the data is in XML format, the other one is JSON, and then both files are zipped (pkzip). How would they compare regarding the file size? My guess is that they probably have the same size, because zipping would take the more verbose element names of XML.

Just curious, thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're representing mixed content then XML will probably be smaller, because JSON handles mixed content so inefficiently. But then, if you're interested in JSON then you're probably not interested in mixed content. In fact that's why for simple data XML is likely to be larger: the information content of a given message is higher (uses more bits) if it's expressed in a language where there's a larger permitted set of possible messages.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, zipped XML is larger, because it has same amount of information, plus the tags.

Comment: However, XML tags *compress well* so "how much larger?" is the real question -- not much, in my experience. Remember, JSON has "structure" artifacts as well: braces, colons and quotes. For just a *small* set of tags then the GZIP dictionary should be able to compress it nearly identically.

Answer (score 1):

I think XML will be bigger because it contains start and end tags.
For example:

```
Person:
    Name: Naor
    Address: none
```

Become in XML:

```
<Person>
    <Name>Naor</Name>
    <Address>none</Address>
</Person>
```

And in json:

```
Person: {Name:"Naor", Address:"none"}
```

Comment: If the document is a typical XML document, then the same tags will occur very often, so this won't result in a corresponding increase in the compressed size. In fact, the larger the document, the less difference there should be between the XML and JSON compressed sizes.

Comment: @Michael Kay: I really don't know how zip or rar works and how they compress data, but if you look on the Json you see that instad of open tag and close tag you have { and }. And if in xml the same tags will occur very often then the {} will occur very often. So the compressed file will be equivalent to the original file's size differences.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the structure of the file and the compression algorithm, but in general JSON should be smaller in size. I just zipped two files (XML and JSON) with identical data using a standard windows tool, and JSON file had much better result (almost half the size of the original) compared to XML.